# What does @synchronized mean

Tags: ios, objective-c

I meet this code:

```
       @synchronized (self.messageQueue) {
        [self.messageQueue insertObject:messageDictionaryRepresentation atIndex:0];
    }
```

I want to ask for help what this syntax(@synchronized) use for?
Thanks.

Comment: It creates a mutex (mutual exclusion) lock on a resource. While a resource is locked by a thread, other threads will block if they also execute `@synthronize` using as key the same object or class. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1215541/412916 for details.

Comment: Top hit for Google search "synchronized +site:apple.com":   http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Synchronization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html). You find that is "a convenient way to create mutex locks on the fly in Objective-C code". a related question is [What does @synchronized() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317889/what-does-synchronized-do).