# How to handle multiple thread access the sqlite3 with out dblocked error

Tags: ios, multithreading, sqlite

In my application, background sqlite thread is running... in background thread it fetching data from web service and insert or update data into database. if user insert or delete data from foreground,sometimes i am getting crash it display "sqlite dblocked". but it does not return sqlite busy error.

And i tested thread safe mode

```
     NSLog(@" sqlite3_threadsafe() = %d", sqlite3_threadsafe());
```

it display threadsafe is 2.

I want to check if any other db is writing data, if db is writing data.. i want to write data after previous write task is finished.

how to handle these situation..

Answer (score 9):

You can use lock (such as those enumerated in the [Synchronization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) section of the *Threading Programming Guide*) or you can use a dedicated serial queue. For example, create a queue:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t databaseQueue;
```

Instantiate it:

```
self.databaseQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.company.app.database", 0);
```

And whenever you want to interact with the database, you can do

```
dispatch_sync(self.databaseQueue, ^{
    // do your database activity here
});
```

If you want to simplify your life, the [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) library has a [`FMDatabaseQueue`](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabaseQueue.html) object that does much of this for you (as well as greatly simplifying your database interaction in general).

Comment: If I user global queue here will it make difference??

Comment: @MrugeshTank - That's a concurrent queue, so that's not going to help here. In fact, multi-thread access is one of those things that ends up requiring some form of synchronization of the database.

Answer (score 2):

The thread safe mode prevents crashed when multiple threads access the same connection, but it cannot prevent multiple connections from interfering with each other.

You should use a common lock to protect all database transactions; use either a mutex or the [@synchronized directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317889/what-does-synchronized-do).

Comment: i want to check if any other write process is run.. if any other task is running..wait until it finish...is it possible?

Comment: That is what these locks do.

Comment: Can you please tell me then how to handle db lock

Comment: What particular problem do you have with the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html)?

Comment: This is a problem with your code, not with the documentation, which it appears you have not read and understood.

Answer (score 1):

From the [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html):

> Use the SQLITE_THREADSAFE compile-time parameter to selected the threading mode. If no SQLITE_THREADSAFE compile-time parameter is present, then serialized mode is used. This can be made explicit with -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1. With -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0 the threading mode is single-thread. With -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=2 the threading mode is multi-thread.

So it seems you have SQLite in multithreaded mode, but not serialised. In this mode, you cannot use *the same* database connection from different threads, but you will be safe if you open a different connection in each thread.

Comment: yes i am using different thread.. my issue is some times i am getting db is locked error.

Comment: You need to open a different DB connection in each thread, or rebuild SQLite in serialised mode (with SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1).

Comment: I have `sqlite3_threadsafe() == 2` and put this line of code `sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED)` while performing transactions on different threads concurrently. Is it fine?